# Can I use 'SCIP' solver for PYOMO?

Tags: optimization, python, combinatorial-optimization, pyomo, scip

I have an MINLP problem to solve where I was initially using 'ipopt' solver but the solution was not sticking to 'binary/boolean/integer' domain type for a variable. I am not sure which free solver would be good to go?
Also, I understand 'SCIP' is not straight forward to use.

Comment: It would be considered, Pyomo has a nice facility to deal with the NEOS server to use a dozen solvers without any challenging. Would you see this [link](https://neos-guide.org/neos-interfaces#pyomo)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

SCIP used to be a bit challenging to set up with PYOMO as we needed to build the ASL interface. It's been a few years so I don't know if that's changed, but you can find a relevant discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/g/pyomo-forum/c/peBjIvkVwtQ).

What might be easier would be to use [Couenne](https://github.com/coin-or/Couenne), which is a deterministic global optimisation solver for MINLP and works out of the box with PYOMO.

If you are a student/academic, you can also use our own global MINLP solver (Octeract Engine) [for free](https://octeract.com/academic-licences/).

If you do, you can find a detailed tutorial on how to use it with PYOMO on Windows & Linux [here](https://octeract.com/pyomo-with-the-engine/).

Answer (score 5):

You can use SCIP with PYOMO easily. My way is: At first, use an executable SCIP version, it is available for the 7.0 version. After then giving the path of the executable to PYOMO, such as:

```
    solver = SolverFactory('scip', executable="./scip")
```

It works. But I use BONMIN in same way.

Answer (score 5):

With SCIP 8, you can either download the program from https://scipopt.org/ and add it to your search path, or you can install using Anaconda via `conda install scip`.

Once SCIP is installed, you should be able to run `pyomo --solver scip --solver-io nl model.py` or use `SolverFactory('scip', solver_io='nl')` in your Python code.

If you leave off the solver-io option, Pyomo will try to use a SCIP-specific communication method, which didn't work for me. But specifying `--solver-io nl` forces Pyomo to run SCIP in AMPL/ASL mode, which works fine.

You may also be able to get this to run without putting `scip` in your search path, by specifying the full path to the program instead of just `scip`.